# Chrome app log file

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Does anyone have any good ideas for maintaining a log file for a Chrome app? I want to log some information that can be reviewed at a later date but can't really find any information on it.

I thought about using the fileSystem api but not sure if that would work or not. I couldn't find a way to actually save a file using that api that doesn't prompt the user first.

Another approach I considered was using the Chrome local storage api and not actually write a file but just write log entries to that instead.

Any input would be appreciated as to what would be the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: chrome.storage sounds like it would be best here, since you don't actually need a file.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for chrome storage options, there is also websql (deprecated by html5) and indexedDb. Both would work for your case.

Comment: Chrome Apps don't have websql. See crbug.com/339579

Answer (score 0):

In my own viewer I use [launchData object](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_runtime#event-onLaunched) and get file from command line. No prompts. It is possible that using this method you will save the log.
Try [this sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/filesystem-access) for more information.